# MySQL dynamic ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sorting, dynamic, parameters

I have a fairly complex mySQL query with three unions that ultimately need to be sorted and paged.  The use case is a web page with multiple columns of data. The user can select one column at a time for sorting by clicking on the header of the column and then page through the results.  A second click on the header toggles the sort order.  My strategy is to pass in the field ($sortField) to specify the field and a flag ($sortOrder) to specify ascending or descending order.  Based on my web research, I have it working with the statements below, but I'm hitting a sort_buffer limit when I add any more sorting options and am concerned that this solution will ultimately not scale.  Does anyone have a recommendation for a better approach?   Seems like there should be a fairly straight forward solution but I can't seem to find it.

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_cd' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fo_cd END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_cd' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fo_cd END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fm_name' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fm_name END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fm_name' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fm_name END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_ld' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fo_ld END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_ld' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fo_ld END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'us_creator' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN us_creator END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'us_creator' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN us_creator END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'us_assignedTo' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN us_assignedto END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'us_assignedTo' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN us_assignedto END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_currentStatus' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fo_CurrentStatus END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fo_currentStatus' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fo_CurrentStatus END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name1' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fd_name1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name1' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fd_name1 END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name2' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fd_name2 END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name2' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fd_name2 END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name3' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fd_name3 END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name3' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fd_name3 END,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name4' AND $sortOrder = -1 THEN fd_name4 END DESC,
CASE WHEN $sortField = 'fd_name4' and $sortOrder = 1 THEN fd_name4 END
```

Comment: Just how large is the dataset?

Comment: @strawberry -- It's not huge right now, but growing rapidly.  It's a newer SaaS application that I will need to scale over time. The results I am sorting are the product of a three-union select, so that is probably adding some complexity to things.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to you code

do  the fact you are using var  in you code  .. you could simple  use  a dinamic sql  (but keep attention ad a proper sanitize of var content for avoid sqlinjection risk)

```
"  ORDER BY " . $sortField . " CASE WHEN $sortOrder = -1  THEN 'DESC' ELSE ASC 'END' ";
```

or

```
$asc_desc =  ($sortOrder == -1) ? 'DESC' : ASC 
"  ORDER BY " . $sortField . " " .  $asc_desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will look into this; however, as you suggest, this kind of pattern can open things up to injection attacks so I've tried to keep the parameters as parameters handled by the SPROC rather than constructing SQL statements from strings.